# Minimizing 1/x such that x>=1 and x<=10 using CVXPY

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

I am trying to solve the following problem using CVXPY:

```
# Define the variable
x = cp.Variable()

# Define the objective function
objective = cp.Minimize(1/x)

# Define the constraints
constraints = [x >= 1, x <= 10]

# Formulate the problem
problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

# Solve the problem
problem.solve()

# Print the results
print("Optimal value of x:", x.value)
print("Optimal minimum value:", 1/x.value)
```

It gives me the following error:

```
DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The objective is not DCP. Its following subexpressions are not:
1.0 / var8856
```

Now I know that 1/x is not convex but it is convex in the interval [1, 10] so why does CVXPY raise a DCP error.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4703093/339790)

Comment: Is there something wrong with the answer or why have you not accepted it? You can always leave comments if there is something you don't understand.

Comment: I was a bit inactive on stackoverflow. I accepted it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good question,

Here is what I suggest.
Always check that the equation you are solving is following DCP Rules.
You ask how, You can do that by visiting [here](https://dcp.stanford.edu/analyzer?expr=1%2Fx). (I have entered '1/x' but you can remove it and check any equation).

As you can see below, it is classified as Unknown.
[image]

Next, you can replace your function with an atomic function, check this [link](https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/functions/index.html#:%7E:text=none-,inv_pos(x),-1).
There are multitude of defined atomic functions that follow DCP rules at the predefined intervals, so always use them(since you will be defining the constraints)
Below is the working code.

```
# Define the variable
x = cp.Variable()

# Define the objective function
objective = cp.Minimize(cp.inv_pos(x))

# Define the constraints
constraints = [x >= 1, x <= 10]

# Formulate the problem
problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

# Solve the problem
problem.solve()

# Print the results
print("Optimal value of x:", x.value)
print("Optimal minimum value:", 1/x.value)
```

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the DCP Analyzer resource. I had no clue of these atomic functions either.
Thanks!